# Data mismatch between OpenCV Mat matrix and Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

I read an image ans converted the data to an Eigen matrix.  When I tried to read the data at the same pixel in both the matrices, I gent different values.  What am I doing wrong?  My assumption was both cout below will give the same value but I am getting different values.

```
    img.convertTo(img, CV_64F);
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>> imgMap(img.ptr<double>(),img.rows,img.cols);
    cout<<img.at<double>(50,0);
    cout<<imgMap(50,0);
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's the same pixel? There could be differences in the way the data is stored. By default, Eigen uses column-major storage order. This has an impact on the matrix resulting from `Map`. I would try and check if the mismatch persists if you use  `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> imgMap...`

Comment: @RHertel That worked.. thanks a lot..